# How to order views' layers on top of each others in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

[image: How to bring the red view to be on top of the border of the text field?]

I added the redView as a subView of the textField and used AutoLayout to constraint it to be as it appears in the image, but the problem here now is
I want to bring the red view to be on top of the border
I tried to use this method
`bringSubviewToFront(floatingPlaceholderContainer)`
but it didn't work, also tried to use the layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude and it also didn't work

Edit-
the code I used and didn't work as I expected

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.redlayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.redlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: -10, width: 100, height: 30)
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.redlayer)
        self.redlayer.zPosition = 10
    }
```

and this is the result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the *timing* of when you're adding this layer. This approach works fine for me:

```
class MyTextField : UITextField {
    let redlayer = CALayer()
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.redlayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.redlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: -10, width: 100, height: 30)
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.redlayer)
        self.redlayer.zPosition = 10
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: but may you please illustrate how could I draw the border myself?

Comment: See my edit, actually what I said originally was not quite right. :)

Comment: Actually I tried this and it didn't work, the red view still appears under the textField border

Comment: Well, that's interesting, but then we have to explain why that's not true on my machine. Added a screen shot as proof. Please note that I've shown you the entirety of my code, but you have not shown me _any_ of your code.

Comment: Your code only works when you don't assign values to the textField border color and border width, if I work with the default border which the textField offers , then your solution will be a great fit, but when it comes to border customization, it won't work , please check the updated question with the results I got when applying your code snippet.